# Determinar horário em função

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php $ler = $_COOKIE['viu']; if($ler == "1") :?>
<?php include 'libera.php';?>



<?php else :?>

<?php include 'bloqueia.php';?><?php endif; ?>
```

Quero modificar o código acima da seguinte forma:

Quero trabalhar com horários. Se `ler == 1` ou for de 00:00 até 11:59 aí vai para o `libera.php`.

Mas se for 12:00 até 23:59 e ler não for igual a 1, aí vai para o `bloqueia.php`.

Comment: faltou postar o código

Comment: Agora deu certo rsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) para obter o horário atual.

Só lembrando que esta função - apesar do nome - retorna uma string. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368132/112052) sugere retornar o horário no formato "hh:mm:ss" e comparar com a string `"00:00:00"`. Isso só "funciona" por coincidência, já que comparação de strings leva em conta a ordem lexicográfica dos caracteres. O detalhe é que a condição deveria ser `($hora >= "00:00:00") && ($hora <= "11:59:59")` (usando `>=` e `<=` em vez de `>` e `<`), caso contrário tanto a meia-noite quanto 11:59:59 serão ignorados.

Mas se você pensar bem, para verificar se o horário está entre 00:00 e 11:59, você só precisa verificar o valor da **hora** (tanto faz os minutos e segundos):

```
$hora = date('H');
if ($ler == 1 || ($hora >= 0 && $hora < 12)) {
    // horário entre 00:00 e 11:59
}
```

`date('H')` retorna uma string com o valor da hora entre "00" e "23" (veja na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)). Porém, ao comparar `$hora >= 0`, o PHP [converte o valor de `$hora` para número](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Claro que, se quiser, também pode explicitamente converter o valor para um número, usando [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php):

```
$hora = intval(date('H'));
```

Sendo assim, se o valor da hora for maior ou igual a zero **e** menor que 12, eu sei que o horário está entre 00:00 e 11:59 (tanto faz o valor dos minutos e segundos, nem preciso verificá-los).

*Na verdade, como a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) garante que o valor sempre estará entre zero e 23, bastaria testar se ele é menor que 12.*

---

#### Fuso-horário

Só lembrando que `date` vai pegar o valor do horário atual usando o timezone que estiver setado no PHP. Ex:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('H'); // 18

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo date('H'); // 03
```

De acordo com o timezone setado, o valor do horário atual muda (em Londres, agora são 18h, enquanto em Tóquio são 3 da manhã). Ou seja, será considerado o horário que está configurado no servidor em que o PHP está rodando, independente de onde estiver o usuário que está acessando o seu site.

Comment: $hora = date('H');
if ($ler == 1 || ($hora >= 18 && $hora < 0)) {
    // horário entre 18:00 às 23:59
}

Ta certo desta forma que mandei acima tbm, caso eu quero que verifique no horario das 18hrs até 23:59?

Comment: @RafaelMacedo Pense assim: se a hora for maior que 18, então ela com certeza não é menor que zero, ou seja, nunca vai entrar nesse `if` (quer dizer, vai entrar se `$ler == 1`, mas a parte do horário vai ser sempre falsa). Basta fazer `$hora >= 18` - ou, se quiser ser mais explícito, `$hora >= 18 && $hora <= 23` (apesar de ser redundante, já que `date('H')` sempre retorna valores entre 0 e 23, então não precisaria testar se é menor que 23)

Comment: Ultima vez que te pertubo, mas confere isso aqui ta ver se minha logica ta certa: http://prntscr.com/mxkp62

Quero que se ler == 1 ou horario for maior que 18hrs, ai abre o premium.php, caso contrario, ai abre o bloq.php. Ta certo dessa forma que fiz ai no print?

Comment: @RafaelMacedo Sim, é isso mesmo! :-)

Comment: Cara, e no seu exemplo você fez, você colocou ($hora >= 0 && $hora < 12) para o intervalo de meia noite até meio dia. Mas segundo sua logica que você falou ai por ultimo, eu posso usar assim tbm? Ja que se for menor que 12, automaticamente vai ser maior que 0. 

$hora = date('H');
if ($ler == 1 || $hora < 12) {
    // horário entre 00:00 e 11:59
}

Comment: @RafaelMacedo Sim, como eu disse na resposta, bastaria testar se ele é menor que 12 :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$hora = date("H:i:s");
$ler = $_COOKIE['viu'];

  if( $ler == 1 || (($hora > "00:00:00") && ($hora < "11:59:59")) )
    redirect('libera.php');
  else
    redirect('bloqueia.php');

?>
```

Comment: Valeu, cara. Obrigado